# how to add menu heading in bootstra

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        Ribbon
    </title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .removeBtm {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        .projClr {
            border-color: #69cee6;
            background: #70ddf7;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .iconNav li a {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 80px;
        }

        .forHover .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .forHover .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
            color: orange;
        }

        .navbar {
            border-radius: 0px;
        }

        .leftBorder {
            padding-right: 5px;
            border-right: 4px solid white;
            height: 127px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default removeBtm projClr">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    EVALUTION
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-1
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-2
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-3
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Demo Liceance
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-cog "></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-1
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-2
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-3
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse removeBtm">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        File
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Patient
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Account
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Claims
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Tools
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Utilities
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Reports
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        ManageMyHealth
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        ConnectedCare
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        CBIT
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        ToolBar
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Help
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="caret">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-1
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-2
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-3
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <table class="buttonHolderTable" style="height: auto !important;overflow:hidden;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: normal;text-align: left;padding-right: 293px;padding-top: 6px;padding-bottom: 6px;">
                PATIENT
            </th>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: normal;text-align: left;padding-right: 557px;">
                APPOINMENT
            </th>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: normal;text-align: left;padding-right: 57px;">
                TASK MANAGER
            </th>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: normal;text-align: left;padding-right: 364px;">
                INBOX
            </th>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: normal;text-align: left;padding-right: 61px;">
                SMS
            </th>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: normal;text-align: left;padding-right: 146px;">
                MISC
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default removeBtm forHover">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav iconNav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <p>
                            New
                        </p>
                        <span class="caret">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-1
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-2
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Page 1-3
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-search fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Search
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-address-card fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Patient Register
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="leftBorder">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-desktop fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Kiosk Action
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Apponment Books
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-book fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Apponment pad
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Queue Workflow
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Status Screen
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-bell-o fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Waiting List
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-user-secret fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Admin Notes
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Worklist
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="leftBorder">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-clipboard fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Widget
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Staff Task
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="leftBorder">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-user-plus fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Patient Task
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-inbox fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Provider Inbox
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-eraser fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Scanning
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-paperclip fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Attachment Manager
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-id-card-o fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Recall Contact
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="leftBorder">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Notifications Inbox
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="leftBorder">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Compose SMS
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-tag fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Label
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-television fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Open User Workspace
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-users fa-2x">
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            Search Address Book
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You nedd to be more specific so that people understand your problem.Also you should format your code properly (ctrl+k)

Comment: What's your question?